# Can't implement TextWatcher in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

[My implementation of TextWatcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK6zB.jpg)

[The Error it showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3SGR.jpg)

I am trying to implement TextWatcher in kotlin it got this error. How to fix this

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply implement `TextWatcher` using anonymous class like this:

```
binding.editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
})
```